# My MySQL prepared statement won't work

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have a MySQL statement that won't work for me. I've checked several parts of the code but it keeps returning null as the result. I've also tried replacing the `WHERE enc_mail = AND enc_public_id=" to "WHERE 1"` to check if it was a problem with the variables, but it is not. I did not get errors either.

```
  $connect_db = mysqli_connect("myhost","my username","my password","my db");

    $mail_id = crypto(mysqli_real_escape_string($connect_db,htmlspecialchars($_GET['em'])),'e');
    $public_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect_db,htmlspecialchars($_GET['public']));
    $active_true = true;
    $check = $connect_db->prepare("SELECT active FROM enc_data WHERE enc_mail=? AND enc_pub_id=?");
    $check->bind_param("ss", $mail_id, $public_id);
    $active = $check->execute();

        if($active[0]=="" ){
        //It goes here once the code is run
    }
```

Comment: i do not see you checking for erros here.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to use both `real_escape_string()` **_and_** parameterized variables. Parameterized variables are good enough on it's own :) That includes any other string cleaning too, none of it is necessary if you are using parameterized variables. Getting rid of all of that will definitely help the readability of your code.

Comment: @garethpower Please add back the error logging part so we see how you check for errors

Comment: also `execute()` returns true/false

Comment: One, sec I'm getting the error logging. See I let $result = $stmt->execute() on another page and $result['data'] worked fine from there

Comment: I recommend switching to `PDO`. If you need help learning how to use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for safe and secure queries, then you can check [GrumpyPDO](https://github.com/GrumpyCrouton/GrumpyPDO) (A class I wrote) which makes [Prepared Statements](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) easy, and clean. Alternatively you should learn more about [Prepared Statements for MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Sorry my original answer was using PDO and I don't want to confuse. A note - you may want to use "si" as the second bind param appears to be an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply `bind_result` and then `fetch`

Also there is absolutely no reason to `escape_string` when using prepared statements as @GrumpyCrouton said

i would recommend you switch to PDO as it is more straightforward

Comment: Hey if you are a fan of PDO you should check out the [class I wrote](https://github.com/GrumpyCrouton/GrumpyPDO) and let me know if you see anything I can do better

Comment: 1) As it is mentioned in the docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php
2) usually first modify/crypt/something a string and then/lastly escape it, except when using it as parameter to a prepared statement
3) +1 for PDO :-)

Comment: @clemens321 Because if you escape the string before doing anything else it will change the result of the modify/crypt/whatever :P

Comment: i'll check it out now @GrumpyCrouton

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton. Solid work. Just a note, a major overhaul in the class you wrote would be to have a function which dynamically inserts/updates into the database using prepared statements.just pass the array as column value, then the column would be the named parameters as in :name,:age, then prepared statements, Viola!

Comment: +1 for recommending no escape string and for recommending PDO, but for what it's worth, you can use mysqli without bind_result(). You can use [mysqli_stmt_get_result()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) and then call methods on the result like fetch_assoc(), etc. It makes using mysqli a little more tolerable, but I still like PDO better.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton That's why I said usually :-) . Don't get the `htmlspecialchars()` here as it *usually* is a pre-output filter. I hope there is not too much in the db yet to change it safely.

Comment: @Akintunde You can already do that with the class though, along with any other DML queries https://github.com/GrumpyCrouton/GrumpyPDO/wiki/Usage---DML-(INSERT,-UPDATE,-DELETE)

Comment: It makes me wonder, why you ventured to answer, apparently having no experience with Mysqli at all

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Akintunde that you should NOT use escaping and htmlspecialchars on query parameters. Escaping is redundant when you use query parameters. htmlspecialchars is just when you *output* content to HTML, not for input to SQL.

You don't necessarily have to use bind_result() for a mysqli query. You can get a result object from the prepared statement, and then use fetch methods on the result object to get successive rows.

Here's how I would write your code:

```
// makes mysqli throw exceptions if errors occur
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

$connect_db = new mysqli("myhost", "my username", "my password", "my db");

$mail_id = $_GET['em'];
$public_id = $_GET['public'];
$active_true = true;
$sql = "SELECT active FROM enc_data WHERE enc_mail=? AND enc_pub_id=?";
$stmt = $connect_db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $mail_id, $public_id);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if($row["active"]=="" ){
        //It goes here once the code is run
    }
}
```

But in fact I would prefer to use PDO instead of mysqli, so I guess that's not *really* how I would write the OP's code. :-)

Comment: It should be noted that get_result is not guaranteed to be available which could make a problem

Comment: @YourCommonSense, as far as I know `get_result()` requires the **mysqlnd** driver, and then it's available. Is there any other reason it wouldn't be available?

Comment: Yes, that's the reason exactly.

Comment: Well, PHP distributions enable the mysqlnd driver by default for all mysql extensions since 5.4.0 (2012-03-01). I think it's pretty safe to depend on it being available. You could argue that PDO or mysqli or PHP itself might not be "available." It's true—like any software, you do have to make sure those packages are installed before you can use them!

Comment: If you say, "some people have not upgraded to PHP 5.4.0," I'll answer that they're using unsupported software. Both PHP 5.4 and PHP  5.5 are past their official end of support.

Comment: mysqlnd is unrelated to version, you can have even PHP7 without it

Comment: Only if you build it that way deliberately. This is not a convincing argument to avoid using `get_result()`.

Comment: I am not building PHP instances, I just humble answering questions on Stack Overflow and I see A LOT asking why get_result() is not there. there is no argument to avoid using get_result() when it's available but one have to be aware that it could be not. so my very first comment stated